# Does different port number of different ip and transport protocol on the same machine differ

Tags: sockets, networking, tcp, udp, ip

Let's say, I have a nic, it has two addresses 10.0.1.1 and 10.0.1.2, and I have four processes with one socket each, 1 is using tcp with 10.0.1.1:30, 2 is using udp with 10.0.1.1:30, 3 is using tcp with 10.0.1.2:30, 4 is using udp 10.0.1.2:30.

Are those four socket's all receive the same packets or who differs from who?
Does the fact that four sockets are in one process affect the result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sockets are identified by not only their IP/Port pairs, but also by their transports.  That is why you have to specify the socket type when creating a socket, before it is even bound.  So it is perfectly OK to have a TCP socket and a UDP socket both bound to the same IP/Port pairs, since their transports are different.  A UDP packet cannot be routed to a TCP socket, and vice versa (they can be routed to a RAW socket, though).  It makes no difference whatsoever if they are being used in the same process or in different processes.

Comment: So, if I bind a tcp socket and a raw socket to the same IP/Port, then they will receive the same package or they would compete for the same packages?

Comment: It depends on which protocol the RAW socket is using.  If it is using TCP, one of the binds will fail since they are trying to bind to the same TCP IP/Port, which can only be bound once at a time.

Comment: Ports don't exist outside of the protocol.  You could have a protocol with ports with letters if you wanted.  There is no concept of ports conflicting between TCP and UDP because a port isn't an independent concept.  Ever heard of an IP socket?  I didn't think so.  This is why.

Comment: @dspjm   raw sockets don't have ports.

Answer (score 1):

You have:

TCP 10.0.1.1:30
UDP 10.0.1.1:30
TCP 10.0.1.2:30
UDP 10.0.1.2:30

They are all different. No *packet* intended for one of them can possibly be delivered to another.

Reasons:

1. TCP and UDP ports occupy different namespaces.
2. Each IP address has its own set of ports.

So there is no overlap, ambiguity, sharing, ...

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it's clear, but Remy's answer seems to be more detailed....

Comment: Agreed. I've improved mine a bit.

Comment: I dont think each IP address has its own set of ports. Each address family does have its own set of ports. THus, we would have a set of ports for each of the following combinations: TCP for IPv4 addresses, TCP for IPv6 addresses, UDP for IPv4 addresses, and UDP for IPv6 addresses. Each set consists of 64K numbers.

Answer (score 1):

EJP has given the right answer. In adition even though all the sockets are in the same process but still they will be receiving different packets.

Comment: Or the same thread, or the same class, or the same object, or the same CPU, or ... 'No' means no. You don't need to qualify it.